# Is there a design pattern or basic object-oriented principle that deals with this case of shared resources?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, shared-resource

Let's say I have three classes, `Solid`, `Face`, and `Edge` that are defined as follows:

```
class Solid{
    public:
        // perform an action on a single edge.
        void addFillet(int edgeNum);
        // perform an action on a single face
        void addBore(int faceNum);
        // perform an action on all faces and edges
        void move(Pos newPosition);
    private:
        std::vector<Edge*> edges;
        std::vector<Face*> faces;
};

class Face{
    public:
        // will modify a subset of edges
        virtual void changeHeight(int newHeight) = 0;
    private:
        int myNum;
        std::vector<Edge> edges;
}

class Edge{
    public:
        virtual void changeLength(int newLength) = 0;
    private:
        int myNum;
        int length;
}
```

in this example, `Solid` manages a 'superset' of `Edge`s. Each `Face` that `Solid` manages will have a 'sub-set' of `Solid.edges`. Further, any two `Solid.faces` may have a common `Edge`.

My question: are there any design patterns or general object-oriented principles for dealing with situations like this? How can I manage the relationship between `Solid.edges` and `Face.edges`? More specifically

Comment: Well typically you only store the Edge buffer in the Solid object, and for each Face you store an index to the Edge's it owns. (Drawing parallel with conventional computer rendering which stores vertices)

Comment: As @meowgoesthedog mentioned this is similar to how OpenGL handles [Vertex Arrays](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). One object owns (and by that I mean handles allocation) the actual vertices, while the others refer to them by id.

Comment: You likely want to have a `shared_ptr<Edge>` held in `Solid` and `Face`. Unless `Solid` is the ultimate owner, then you may want a `weak_ptr` in `Face`.

Comment: Shouldn't the fundamental types be points (0D)? Now, if you change a face of the solid, its faces may no longer join up. On the other hand, if your fundamental objects are points, then if you change a point, the edges and faces and hence the solid will still join up.

Comment: @walter, ultimately, I'd like to add `Vertex` to this design, which again `Solid` has access too but primarily `Edge` manages. I wanted to keep the example simple though.

Comment: @AndyG I liked the idea of using `shared_ptr<Edge>` etc. in `Solid`. I suppose, then, that `Solid`s constructor would have to accept a vector of `shared_ptr<Edge>` and `shared_ptr<Face>`. I can then use @CoryKramer and @meowgoesthedog's suggestion to pass each `Face` and `Edge` an index - and I guess a reference to `Solid`s vectors?

So, is there name for a design pattern of this style? If so I'd like to do some reading/research on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of managing these sorts of relationships but if you want efficiency and you want to share vertices between edges and share edges between faces then I suggest your `Solid` should own a complete list of `Vertex` and `Edges`.

Then `Edge` has some sort of non-owning reference to its vertices and `Face` has some sort of non-owning reference to its edges. Those non-owning references could be something like a pointer but you then have to be careful you don't invalidate those pointers by reallocating the main list of vertices or edges. It is safer if you store indices instead. But that does mean you have to refer to `Solid` to find out what a vertex/edge index refers to:

```
class Solid {
  std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
  std::vector<Edge> edges;
  std::vector<Face> faces;

public:
  Solid(std::vector<Vertex> vertices) : vertices(std::move(vertices)) {}

  void addEdge(int vertex_index1, int vertex_index2) {
    edges.emplace_back(vertex_index1, vertex_index2);
  }
  void addFace(std::vector<int> edge_indices) {
    faces.emplace_back(std::move(edge_indices));
  }
  const Vertex &getVertex(int vertex_index) const { return vertices[vertex_index]; }
  const Edge &getEdge(int edge_index) const { return edges[edge_index]; }
};

class Edge {
  int vertex_first;
  int vertex_second;

public:
  Edge(int vertex_first, int vertex_second)
      : vertex_first(vertex_first), vertex_second(vertex_second) {}

  const Vertex &getVertexFirst(const Solid &solid) const {
    return solid.getVertex(vertex_first);
  }
  const Vertex &getVertexSecond(const Solid &solid) const {
    return solid.getVertex(vertex_second);
  }
};

class Face {
  std::vector<int> edge_indices;

  int getEdgeIndex(int face_edge_index) const {
    return edge_indices[face_edge_index];
  }

public:
  Face(std::vector<int> edge_indices) : edge_indices(std::move(edge_indices)) {}

  const Edge &getEdge(int face_edge_index, const Solid &solid) const {
    return solid.getEdge(getEdgeIndex(face_edge_index));
  }
};
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/75t5q4xqg7nueavm).

An alternative is to use `std::shared_ptr` for `Edge` and `Vertex` but then you have to pay for the dynamic memory allocation and poorer data locality.

It is tempting to store a back-reference to `Solid` inside `Face` and `Edge` for better encapsulation. You could do that but then the `vector` of `Face` and `Edge` effectively contain a lot of duplicate pointers. If that sort of encapsulation is important to you I suggest you create some sort of wrapper classes for working with edges and faces that contain the raw edge/face object and also a back-reference to the `Solid`.